# 3D graphic frameworks for C#

Tags: c#, directx, managed-directx

I have a application for visualizing map data. Until today i have managed with using standard Forms.Graphics to draw 2D lines and other primitives in my windows application.

I found out today that Managed C# DirectX is deprecated. Is there any alternatives for me as a C# developer if I want use 2D/3D in my application? (it's not a game so i will not migrate to C++). I have no need for anything advanced. All I need is to be able to draw lines and faces in 2D and in 3D and to pick objects with the mouse in 2D and in 3D.

Comment: You should try the XNA framework and OpenTK.NET library.

Comment: If what you are doing is not game related you could try using WPF's 3d support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move to [WPF Meshs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24727/WPF-3D-Part-1-of-n) to draw basic shapes in 3D.

Or you can move to [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) and use this gaming framework for 3D.

You can also use XNA inside WPF.

Forms is best used with the MVP Pattern and i personally think that MVVM is superior. MVVM works great with WPF so you ahould migrate if you have the choice.

I dont see that DirectX is going away soon. There are some developers who want more direct control over graphics but i currently dont see that this will impact the existance of managed graphics in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try OpenGL?

Some libraries:

http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=opengl&lang=en